# VnPy - Does VnTrader has an English version?

Tags: chinese-locale

I just cloned and run VnTrader on my Ubuntu 16-04 machine. The application is in Chinese and I can't find a way to change the language. How can I **change the language of VnTrader to English?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

VnTrader has an English Version, to change it you need to hard-code the language you want into the file *examples/VT_setting.json*

```
{
"fontFamily": "微软雅黑",   
...

"language": "english",

...
"maxDecimal": 4
}
```